# How do you write a menu driven python programme

Tags: python, menu

Here's the question:

Write a menu-driven Python program which includes the following;

- A function which takes a file name from the user and creates a file of the same name. The function should then use a while loop to process the file and allow the user to input a number of integers which are to be written to the file.
- A function which uses a `for` loop to read the contents of the file and outputs them to the screen.
- A function to append a number of integers to the File.
- A function which calculates the total of the numbers contained in the file and prints the
  answer to the screen

Here's the code I've done so far, I just need help finishing it off:

```
def main():
    filename = input("Welcom, please enter file name:\t")
    menu()
    choice= int(input("Enter menu choice:\t"))

    while choice != 5:
        #get file choice from user
        if choice == 1:
            #create file
            create(filename)
        elif choice == 2:
            #read file
            read(filename)
        elif choice == 3:
            #append file
            append(filename)
        elif choice == 4:
            #get total
            get_total(filename)

        choice = int(input("Enter menu choice:\t"))

    print("\nApplication Complete")

def menu():

    #user chooses a number from list
    print("Choose a number to continue:\t\n\
    Select 1 to create a file\n\
    Select 2 to read a file\n\
    Select 3 to append to a file\n\
    Select 4 to calculate the total of a file\n\
    Select 5 to exit programme")

def create(filename):

    #open file name
    outfile = open(filename,"w")
    again = "y"

    while again == "y":

        try:
            num = int(input("Input number:\t")
            outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")
            #asks user whether they want to continue or not
            again = input("Enter y to continue:\t")

        except ValueError:
                      print("An error occured,please enter an integer:\t")

        except:
                      print("An undetermined error occurred")
    #close file
    outfile.close()

def read(filename):

    read(filename)
    print("\nReading File)

    try:
        infile = open(filename,"r")

        for line in infile:

        number = int(line)
        print(number)

    except IOError:
            print("An error occured trying to read")
            print("the file", filename)

    except:
            print("An undefined error occurred")

def append(filename):

    append(filename)

    print("\nAppending to file")

    try:
        #create file object
        outfile = open(filename, "a")
        again = "y"

    while again == "y":

        try:
            num = int(input("input number to append to file:\t"))
            outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")
            again = input ("enter y to continue:\t")

        except ValueError:
                print("an error occured please an integer")
        except:
                print("an undefined error occured")

    except IOError:
            print("an error occurred trying to read")
            print("the file", filename)

    except:
            print("an undefined error occurred")

            infile.close()



#call main
main()
```

It keeps saying there's an invalid syntax up in the `create` function with  `outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")`. Also, could someone help me write a function that calculates the total of the numbers contained in the file and prints the answer to the screen please? I'm using python 3.3.2.

Ok so I got the code working, I just need help with writing a function to calculate the total of the numbers contained in the file and print the answer to the screen to finish it if anyone wants to help please

Comment: you're missing a `)` in the line above it

Comment: For "Also, could someone help me write a function that calculates the total of the numbers contained in the file and prints the answer to the screen please?": No, nobody can do that in the middle of a completely separate question. Post a new question, and try to make it a specific question with a specific answer, not a request for hand-holding. (Click the Help link for help on writing good questions.)

Comment: if u read the full question that was part of the question, i asked for help to finish the code, that was part of the code i was unable to do

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a trivial typo on the line above:

```
num = int(input("Input number:\t")
```

Two `(` but only one `)`, so Python thinks this expression continues onto the next line, and of course a call to `outfile.write` can't directly follow a call to `input` like that, so it's a `SyntaxError`.

This is something everyone has to learn once early in their Python experience: When you get an incomprehensible `SyntaxError` on a line, look at the line above and see if you're missing a `)`, `]`, or `}`.

Meanwhile, you might want to consider using a smarter editor that matches brackets for you.